# Failsafe Maven plugin separate selenium project

Tags: selenium, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a selenium project separated from the web project.

I would like to use the Failsafe Maven plugin, but I am not sure if I can point in suiteXmlFiles label to the testng.xml file from another project. I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugins>
   [...]
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.20</version>
      <configuration>
         <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
         </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
   [...]
</plugins>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Can you show us your research?

Comment: I have researched about its configuration, which should be as in this snippet: `code` <plugins> [...] <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.20</version> <configuration> <suiteXmlFiles> <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile> </suiteXmlFiles> </configuration> </plugin> [...] </plugins> `code`

Comment: And my doubt is if I have to put my selenium test project code in the main project, or if it is viable to have this project separated.